# Android Studio appcompat support library

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, implementation

My problem is I want to implement a support design library and it has to match the library's version with the appcompat version. My appcompat version is '''  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0' '''
and support design library's oldest version is 26.1.0 .It doesnt match. How can I change my appcompat version ??

my buid.gradle :

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.2'
```

// implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

Comment: androidx is the new version of support library, the support library has been deprecated and you should use androidx

Comment: It's also `app COMPAT` not `appCombat` (which made me laugh, because we've all fought appCompat for years...)

Comment: What should I do ?

Comment: @dinkar_kumar  Sorry :)) just Trying things. What should I do ?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini what should I do :)))

Comment: It depend upon what you were using, like if you were using snackbar from design then you can use material design dependency

Comment: @dinkar_kumar oh I see. Thank you

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: did that worked for you ?

Comment: kinda worked but I need to use coordinator layout when I do whole xml page doesn't show anything and I thought it was about support design How can I use properly Coordonator layout @dinkar_kumar

Comment: maybe about floating action button I couldn't understand